# bundle install Ruby cups gem fails on OSX Mavericks

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, cups

Recently got a new OSX Mavericks laptop.  Now the cups gem (https://github.com/m0wfo/cups) will no longer install.

I'm receiving the following error output from bundle install.

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.                                    [1/1815]

        /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
checking for main() in -lcups... yes
checking for cups-config... yes
cups version:
1.7.0
creating Makefile

make
/usr/bin/clang -I. -I. -I/Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/lib/ruby/1.8/i686-darwin13.0.1 -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DA$WIN_C_SOURCE   -fno-common  -D_IPP_PRIVATE_STRUCTURES  -c cups.c
In file included from cups.c:1:
./ruby_cups.h:6:12: fatal error: 'ruby/st.h' file not found
  #include <ruby/st.h>
           ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [cups.o] Error 1


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@uiris3/bundler/gems/cups-d44bfc9edafe for inspect
ion.
Results logged to /Users/bigtunacan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374@uiris3/bundler/gems/cups-d44bfc9edafe/ext/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing cups (0.1.7), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install cups -v '0.1.7'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Took a look at the github repo and they said it should be working with master; so I am pointing directly to the github repo for now, but the error remains the same.

```
gem 'cups', :git => 'https://github.com/m0wfo/cups'
```